# Data frame casting not throwing overflow exception and produces null

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
```

I am trying to cast the data frame to `df.column.cast(ShortType())` but when I tried to insert data 99999 it is converting to null without throwing any error, So can you suggest any approach to throw the error while converting.

Answer (score 4):

Spark does not throw if a cast goes wrong.

As a custom approach to catch those errors you could write a [UDF](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-udf-user-defined-function/) that throws if you cast to null. This worsens the performance of your script though, since Spark can not optimise UDF executions.

Answer (score 0):

Spark will fail silently if `pyspark.sql.Column.cast` fails, i.e. the entire column will become `NULL`. You have a couple of options to work around this:

1. If you want to detect types at the point reading from a file, you can read with a predefined (expected) schema and `mode=failfast` set, such as:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,0,0,2),(1,1,1,1)],['c1','c2','c3','c4'])
df.toPandas().to_csv("./test.csv")
spark.read.csv("./test.csv").show()
+----+---+---+---+---+
| _c0|_c1|_c2|_c3|_c4|
+----+---+---+---+---+
|null| c1| c2| c3| c4|
|   0|  1|  0|  0|  2|
|   1|  1|  1|  1|  1|
+----+---+---+---+---+
```

Running `spark.read.schema("_c0 INT, _c1 INT, _c2 INT, _c3 INT, _c4 INT").option("mode", "failfast").csv("./test.csv").show()` throws:
`org.apache.spark.SparkException: Malformed records are detected in record parsing. Parse Mode: FAILFAST.` because the records in `_c1` through `_c4` are strings in the first row (since `header=False` by default so headers are treated as rows). This can be found deeper in the stacktrace: `Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "_c1"`. To compare, running

```
spark.read.schema("_c0 INT, c1 INT, c2 INT, c3 INT, c4 INT").option("mode", "ignore").csv("./test.csv").show()
+----+----+----+----+----+
| _c0|  c1|  c2|  c3|  c4|
+----+----+----+----+----+
|null|null|null|null|null|
|   0|   1|   0|   0|   2|
|   1|   1|   1|   1|   1|
+----+----+----+----+----+
```

But will throw the following warning `WARN ParseMode: ignore is not a valid parse mode. Using PERMISSIVE.`

2. Your second option is to use an UDF (or even better, a `pandas_udf` since it's vectorized). Here you're running the risk of encountering hard-to-debug errors with type matching, as you're trying to match types Python/Pandas use vs the JVM types PySpark uses. An example of this would be:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df2 = spark.createDataFrame([("a",0,0,2),("b",1,1,1)],['c1','c2','c3','c4'])
df2.show()
+---+---+---+---+
| c1| c2| c3| c4|
+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  0|  0|  2|
|  b|  1|  1|  1|
+---+---+---+---+


@f.pandas_udf("long")
def my_cast(column):
  return column.astype("int64")

df2.select(my_cast(f.col("c1"))).show()
```

This action will throw: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'b'`